# Django tastypie model attribute of format

Tags: django, tastypie

Simple problem.  What happens when you have the name "format" as an attribute of a model with TastyPie?

How do you handle the query for `http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/v1/library_type/?format=json?` when you have a Model which looks like this.

```
class LibraryType(models.Model):
    """The information about each library type."""
    format = models.IntegerField(choices=LIBRARYTYPE_CHOICES)
    equiv = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='remark')
```

You end up with:

```
{
"error": "Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type)."
}
```

Obviously this makes sense but how do you work with it?  The corresponding Resource definition.

```
class LibraryTypeResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = LibraryType.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'library_type'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get',]
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', ]
        filtering = {
            'id': ('exact', ),
            'name': ALL,
            'format': ALL,
            'prefix': ALL,
            'description': ALL,
            'site': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps your `format` is an `IntegerField` and you are passing `format=json` - a string?

Comment: Well if you want to keep filtering by *format* field name the best solution would be to change its name, since *format* key-name is hardcoded and it seems you would have to override or monkey-patch the `determine_format` function to change it..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using only the json format?

If so, you can use the [TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#settings-tastypie-default-formats) to set it as json and never use format=json again.

If not, you can use one of tastypie's hooks to retrieve the format query param and do whatever you want with it.

I would change the name of the query param.